# Integer division vs double division - optimization question

Tags: linux, optimization, cpu, fpu

Which operation should be faster on a x86 CPU on Linux and what are the average differences (in %):

```
unsigned int x, y, z;
x = y / z;
```

or:

```
double x, y, z;
x = y / z;
```

The operation on double will be executed by the FPU and the CPU may continue to other commands. Is it correct?
Does it depend on compilation flags (I'm using gcc with the `-O3` flag)?

Comment: Those are two different operations with different results, and very rarely, if ever, interchangeable. Does it matter if X is slightly faster than Y if you can't switch to the faster alternative?

Comment: +1 to the above. and for the author.. do a batch and run it on a vm let;s say too see the results.

Comment: @dwelch: because I would like to understand the theory, not just to try. I already got few interesting tips from this question (like -mfpmath=sse compiler flag or a fact that conversion from int to double is expensive)...

Comment: understood but I see that as a different question.  The how fast and what percent is a do it yourself thing, the SO question in my mind would be why is this slower than that after you have those results and want to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your work is inherently integer-based, the int-float and float-int conversions may ruin any performance benefit. C's default conversion (truncation) can be particularly slow on older Intel chips.

Apart from that, there are correctness issues with your idea and that's probably sufficient reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An individual floating-point division instruction will take longer than an integer one.  However, if you're doing lots in a row, they'll reach approximately the same rate, due to pipelining (on a modern x86, at least).

Oh, and yes, the CPU can be getting on with other operations whilst the FPU is busy.

Answer (score 0):

Integral operations are generally faster than their floating point counterpart. The difference mostly depends on hardware: some platforms don't even have an FPU.

Such a simple operation shouldn't depend at all on your operating system or on compiler flags: that should be some straight forward assembly instructions.

The best way to find out how much any operation takes is checking your platform's assembly manual or running a benchmark.

Comment: In some cases such as modern 32-bit x86, compiler flags may matter: SSE (gcc `-mfpmath=sse`) may be a faster way to do floating point. With 64-bit this is generally default. Caution: calling conventions may cause incompatibility or poor performance with non-default options.